# Wrong timezone returned by Amadeus on On-Demand Flight Status API

Tags: amadeus

All the On-Demand Flight Status API requests with Indian airport flight points are returning wrong departure and arrival timings. The timezone is +05:30 for IST but the timezone returned by the APIs is +05:00 and the GMT conversion gets wrong with 30 min delay.

Attached is a sample response for UK 511 / 2022-06-03

The time reported by the API is `2022-06-04T07:10+05:00` for BLR.
The correct time of departure is `2022-06-04T07:10+05:30` for BLR.

API is returning the wrong data for all users. Cross verified with another airline (Air India) as well.

[image: API Response]

Comment: Does it only go wrong for BLR or does it also go wrong for other airports with a timezone offset that is not an integer number of hours?

Comment: It's occurring in all airports in India. The timezone offset used for IST is wrong in the API response.

Comment: So, you are saying that you are giving the service the correct data and the response from the service is wrong. Therefore you must contact the service to explain what is happening and what should be happening. Stack Overflow is not the service.

Comment: Hey @AndrewMorton, I am aware of how SO works. The service maintains a tag http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amadeus officially and they want all technical questions to be reported here for a response.

The same is already communicated to the service via email.

For reference, please check https://developers.amadeus.com/support.